# How to make a few div elements responsive

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I'm having trouble with making some of my div elements responsive.

The image with the magnifying glass is refusing to resize when the window is smaller, for example on a ipad. I have tried other methods of resizing but resulting in failure.

Website link: http://onlinestaff.net

Comment: please provide code. I guess it's having property of `position:fixed`

Comment: We cannot help you since reading your entire code is time consuming and useless. Please create a small example with minimal code and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**: The magnifying-glass-image on your website uses the attribute `max-width:none` which causes the image to be displayed in full size even on smaller screens.

**Solution**: When making images responsive we usually use the CSS attribute `max-width:100%` to ensure that big images scale down to fit on the screen (or better: fit into the parent container)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to make divs responsive and their position relative to the size of screen:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-centered pos">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-centered">
                <div class="well"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-centered">
                <div class="well"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-centered">
                <div class="well"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```